# VS2010 Ultimate. Why do I just see "Silverlight 3". Where's 4?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

What do I have to download to be able to set my Silverlight app to version 4? I already downloaded wat I thought was the  latest version of the Silverlight developer runtime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VS 2010 doesn't come with Silverlight 4 support since it wasn't ready when VS 2010 shipped.  You have to download [Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=eff8a0da-0a4d-48e8-8366-6ddf2ecad801&displaylang=en).